# Entity Framework Code first missing foreign key entities in WebAPI project

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, repository, code-first

I'm afraid that if I include my code this post will get too long and too complicated, so I'll try and explain my problem. If however you'd like to see some code illustrating this problem, I'll be happy to add it afterwards.

I have a project, MVC4 project (Website.Web) that used entity framework code first. My entity classes is in a seperate project: Website.Domain

I have a NewsPost class:

```
public virtual int Id { get; set; }
public virtual string Subject { get; set; }
public virtual string Content { get; set; }
public virtual string ImageName { get; set; }
public virtual DateTime CreateTime { get; set; }
public virtual int CreatedById { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
```

And my comments class looks like this:

```
public virtual int Id { get; set; }
public virtual int CreatedById { get; set; }
public virtual DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
public virtual string Content { get; set; }
```

Now in my MVC project, I have entity framework set up with some repository classes and ninject to seperate everything from my controllers. And when I do a "GetAll()" on my newsposts. The NewsPost.Comments will be filled with the comments that's associated with this newspost. It all works perfectly.

Now I got the idea that I'd like to use webapi, so I set up a new MVC basic project. I removed the views folder, and removed the models folder. Then I setup all the repositories here as well along with my entity framework dbcontext class. And enabled migrations on the project to allow me to use entity framework code first in the same fasion as the Website.Web project. I also referenced the same Domain classes as the web project.

Now here comes the problems. I tried doing a GetAll() on the newsposts, but when I inspect the list returned by GetAll(), I see that though it fetches all the news in the database, the COMMENTS are null. I'm pretty sure I have the Website.API set up the same way as my Website.Website.Web - So what am I missing?

I hope I have explained well enough. Again if you need any additional code or I need to clarify some points, I'll happily do this, I just didn't wanna make the question more complicated than it already is with too much code.

Comment: It looks and sounds like you are using a PluralSight course and trying to model your application after it.  My best advice is to go look at Julie Lerman's courses as that course states to understand how to set up your Data Layer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685467.aspx

Comment: kadumel: Thank you for your comment. Yes I initially learned from a pluralsight course, but I have remade the entire thing from bottom up after I got the plural sight one working. So in reality it's not from a pluralsight course...

Comment: To me it doesn't really matter, the point is that you have a Data project in your solution that is not properly set up.  If you don't want to post all of your code and your configurations to get help then you need to go learn from Julie how to set up your EF CodeFirst models.  Actually you just need to go learn from anyone how to do it properly, there are tons of articles out there on this exact topic

Comment: Are the `NewsPost` and the `Comment` class `public` and do they have `public` parameterless constructors?

Comment: Slauma: Yes they are public - But they do not have any constructors - Is this required?

Comment: No, it's not required. No constructor in C# means that there is a parameterless empty public ("hidden") constructor by default. That's OK. I was thinking about the requirements for proxies (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/dd468057). They are a lot (class must not be `sealed` and not `abstract` is another one). If one is not fulfilled EF doesn't create a proxy which means lazy loading won't work = `Comments` will be `null`. Did you check if the `NewsPost`s returned from the repo are proxies? You can see it in the debugger if the type is `DynamicProxyXXXXX....` instead of `NewsPost`.

Comment: Ahh - At some point I must've written this: Context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; - Which causes it to not load the comments like you say. But if I don't prohibit proxy creation it can't serialize into JSON/XML format. But this is another problem.

Thank you Slauma!

Comment: Adding [JsonIgnore] to "public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }" gets the serialization to work as expected